# Is it possible to play only custom maps?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Finally the online editor is out!
The fancommunity can finally share their own work.

So I won't play the casual maps by R*, I want to see what other players created! And I don't want to play only one custom map and then again only casual maps.

So is it possible to play only custom maps which other players created?
When yes, how?
When no, do anyone have some tips to play as much as possible different custom maps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes it is!** - however, currently there is no system in game (either through the phone or the menus) that will allow you to just join games running on custom maps.

To play on custom maps, you currently have to go through the [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com) website, which should already be linked to your console account if you're playing online, then select "games", "Grand Theft Auto V", "GTA online" and then "jobs". At the top there are some drop down menus - filler these to social club members and you will only see community made maps.

It is not currently possible to play multiple custom maps in a row so each time you want to play a custom map (even if you've just finished one) you will have to go through the Rockstar Social Club. With any luck this additional functionality will be added in a future patch although there has been no announcement from Rockstar to this effect at this time.

Comment: I think I'll try it in the next days and take a look how it works. Thanks

Comment: This is good to find other players maps. But when I played one, in the lobby screen, where you can choose the next game, there are again only R* maps. But what I want is to be able to play more than only one custom map in a row.

Comment: The functionality doesn't exist yet, which is why you can't find a way to do it, you currently have to keep choosing the map to play each time you want to play. Hopefully R* will implement something to expand on this in a future patch

Comment: I hope it so much! If you could edit your answer which describe exactly our comments, I'll accept it. The answer right now is more "how can I play custom maps?". Thanks

Comment: @DarkDecipio done!

Comment: In 2 hours you'll get the bounty :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can make a playlist of races, if I'm not mistaken. 
They might've dis-continued that. But it's worth a shot.